# pack fold expression (c++17 extension) available when building with c++14

Tags: c++, g++, c++14, c++17, clang++

The following code contains a fold expression, which afaiu is a c++17 feature:

```
template <typename... T> static bool variable_length_or(const T ... v) {
  return (v || ...);
}

bool foo () {
   return variable_length_or(true, false, true, false);
}
```

what I find odd is that both g++ and clang++ seem to be fine with it when building with `-std=c++14` ([compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'template+%3Ctypename...+T%3E+static+bool+variable_length_or(const+T+...+v)+%7B%0A++return+(v+%7C%7C+...)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Abool+foo+()+%7B%0A+++return+variable_length_or(true,+false,+true,+false)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.333333333333336,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+6.0.0',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)). They do create a warning:

```
<source>:2:16: warning: pack fold expression is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]

 return (v || ...);
```

This somewhat indicates that what I'm writing is not okay before c++17, but the compilation succeeds and the code seems to do what it should. I would've expected the compilation to fail.

Any explanation about why the compiler accepts my fold expression?

(credit where credit is due: I took inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11892759) question, and I could check if all `T` are `bool` similar to what is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29671643))

Comment: If you don't add something as `-ansi -pedantic`, to impose a strict conformance to the standard, the compilers are free to adopt some extensions or, in this case, elements of the following standard.

Comment: Sometimes future features are added to the current compiler version as extensions, if the authors consider that there is no compatibility issues. That is, if the meaning of any valid code changes, then it should be be done, but a brand new syntax can be.

Comment: @max66: Post that as an answer, so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A conforming C++17 compiler has to provide fold expressions. But that's a useful language feature, is it worth actively *disabling* it just because you're compiling in a previous language mode?

Implementations are allowed to provide extensions, provided that they do not alter the behavior of well-formed programs ([[intro.compliance]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.compliance#8)). Fold expressions in pre-C++17 are just such an extension - they're purely additive. So as a question of utility tradeoff between allowing and disallowing fold expressions in C++14 mode, it seems that both gcc and clang decided to lean towards allowing.

Of course, you shouldn't *rely* on this - if you want to write C++17 code, you should compile in C++17. If you want help relying on it, you can compile with [`-pedantic-errors`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-pedantic-errors-1):

> Give an error whenever the base standard (see `-Wpedantic`) requires a diagnostic, in some cases where there is undefined behavior at compile-time and in some other cases that do not prevent compilation of programs that are valid according to the standard. This is not equivalent to `-Werror=pedantic`, since there are errors enabled by this option and not enabled by the latter and vice versa.

Comment: Is it worth actively disabling it? It's not more work than introducing the warning. From what I understood, allowing these kinds of extensions are mostly linked to the amount of effort needed by the Standard Library implementors if the feature ain't available.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't add something as `-ansi -pedantic`, to impose a strict conformance to the standard, the compilers are free to adopt some extensions or, in this case, elements of the following standard.

`-ansi -pedantic` are the options I add for g++ and clang++; other compilers can use different options, obviously.

**-- EDIT --**

As pointed by Barry (thanks!), `-ansi` is no more useful and is enough `-pedantic`.

As pointed by Passer By (thanks!), can be useful the use of `-pedantic-error` to impose an error, and non only a warning, in case of not strictly conformance.

Comment: Uh, just `-pedantic`. Not `-ansi`.

Comment: And you probably want `-pedantic-errors` if you are looking for strict.

Comment: @Barry - I didn't know, thanks: I remember the time when `-ansi` was necessary for `-pedantic` (OK: I admit: I'm old).