# How to constraint the parameter package type in c++11? And How to implement the template in cpp?

Tags: c++11, parameter-passing, variadic-templates

### For the first quesion:

I want to write a function to concatenation the strings, and it can receive multiple strings;

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <class... Args, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename std::decay<Args...>::type, std::string>::type>::type>
std::string foo(const std::string &first, const Args &... senconds) {
    std::string delimiter = "$$";
    std::string ret = first;
    std::vector<std::string> vec{senconds...};
    for (auto second = vec.rbegin(); second != vec.rend(); second++) {
        ret = delimiter + *second + delimiter + ret;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

but when I invoke it like:

```cpp
std::string name = "x";
name = foo(name, "xxx");
```

the compiler will throw an error:

`error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(std::__cxx11::string&, const char [4])’`

and there will be some note:

`note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘<anonymous>’`

I think I should modify the constraint in the template, and I've tried all the related methods in the `type_traits`, but none of them works.

### For the second question:

I want to hide the implementation of some function, but for the template function, it's unable to put the definition in the `.hpp`, and put the implementation in the `.cpp`, the compiler will throw a `undefined reference` error. Is there any elegant way to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: For the second question, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file (and don't get discouraged by the question title). But please also refrain from asking two separate questions at once.

Comment: Aside: you don't need every element of `Args...` to be `std::string`, only something that you can instantiate `std::string` with

Comment: @MaxLanghof, I'll split the two separate questions next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on [MaxLanghof's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59086470/6358876), I changed the template to:

```cpp
template <class... Args,
    typename std::enable_if<var_and<std::is_constructible<
        std::string, Args>::value...>::value>::type * = nullptr>
```

In this form, the function `foo` can be invoked like the `name = foo(name, stringRed, "xxx")`.

Thanks @MaxLanghof again.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit to unwrap here.

- `std::decay<Args...>::type` can't work. `std::decay` takes only a single template argument, but you attempt to expand the pack here. The expansion needs to happen on the `is_same`.
- You are also missing a way to aggregate all the `is_same` predicates. Do you want to `and` them all or `or` them all? Presumably `and`. In C++17 that's easily done with a fold expression, but for C++11 we have to work a bit.
- Finally the thing the compiler complains about: `std::enable_if<bla>::type` evaluates to `void` if `bla` is `true`. That means you're formally expecting a non-type template argument, and the compiler complains because it can't deduce which value of type `void` it should deduce. This is normally alleviated by forming a pointer to it instead and defaulting it to `nullptr`: `std::enable_if<bla>::type* = nullptr`.
- It appears (?) that you expect `foo(someString, "stringLiteral");` to work. It won't, because a string literal is not a `std::string`. Maybe you wanted a different predicate, but for this answer I'll stick with the original condition.

---

Putting all that together:

- In C++17, you would write

  ```
  template <class... Args,
      std::enable_if_t<
              (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Args>, std::string> && ...)
          >* = nullptr
      >
  ```

  https://godbolt.org/z/84Dcmt
- In C++11, we use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11892759/c-variadic-template-and-and-or) helper and add back the `typename` and `::type` verbosity:

  ```
  template <class... Args,
      typename std::enable_if<
          var_and<
              std::is_same<typename std::decay<Args>::type, std::string>::value...
              >::value
          >::type* = nullptr
      >
  ```

  https://godbolt.org/z/2eFyX7

Comment: I've tried the c++11 demo, but if the foo(..) is invoked like foo(name, "xxx"), it still can't find the correct template implementation.

Comment: `<source>:36:12: error: no matching function for call to 'foo'

    name = foo(name, stringRef, name, stringRef, "xxx");` I've modified the code like that.

Comment: And for when I applied this code to my project, there's an error: `error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if<false, void>’`

Comment: @Patrick As I said, with `is_same` you won't be able to pass string literals (see last bullet point). And the error is presumably because you're trying to use it improperly, but I can't diagnose it without seeing what you did. But I see that you figured out something that works for you so, that's good.